# WSO2 API Manager sandbox keys are accepted by production servers

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I just started working with wso2 api manager version 1.6 and it seems that sandbox and production keys can be used interchangeably. Is that a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a Sandbox key, it'll send the request to the sandbox url specified when creating the API. If the sandbox url points to a production backend then, you won't see a difference when switching key types.